# Creating a Team Page with on-click bio

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, onclick

I need to create a pretty simple table that has pictures of our team members (4 total). When one of these images is clicked, I want a 'modal(correct term?)' to open beneath the images and include their biographies, titles, etc. I have included my code below to something that is close to functional, but I cannot figure out how to make one close when the other opens properly.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function showSpoiler(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>

<div class="spoiler">
    <img onclick="showSpoiler(this);" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <h1>John Doe</h1>
    <p>President</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum posuere tempus odio, in ornare lacus pulvinar quis. Aliquam sed risus non nisi euismod dignissim quis quis diam.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum posuere tempus odio, in ornare lacus pulvinar quis. Aliquam sed risus non nisi euismod dignissim quis quis diam. Nullam venenatis sit amet massa eget bibendum. Maecenas odio mi, tristique et viverra ac, ornare id enim. Aliquam et felis nibh. Etiam pharetra, nisi a scelerisque consectetur, nibh quam volutpat dui, nec faucibus ante nunc vel nisi. Fusce rutrum tempor auctor. Donec feugiat tellus in feugiat ultrices. Nulla et neque tristique, dictum metus in, dapibus eros. Duis interdum erat eget pellentesque tristique.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler">
    <img onclick="showSpoiler(this);" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
    This is a spoiler!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler">
    <img onclick="showSpoiler(this);" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
    This is a spoiler!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler">
    <img onclick="showSpoiler(this);" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
    This is a spoiler!
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Visual Reference]

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/hLkgcqxr/1/

My ideas is that when the user clicks '1' it opens below, and when they click '2' it changes to the biography of user 2.

Please let me know if there's any additional info needed in order to push me in the right direction - I know it can be a bit confusing :)

Comment: Before you open a new one, `document.querySelectorAll('.spoiler .inner')` and hide all of them.

Answer (score 1):

This logic relies on a css rule that makes the inner elements hidden, so long as the parent spoiler does not have a class of active.

All our logic does is, when an outer is clicked, it removes the active class from any spoiler that already has it, and then adds the active class to the spoiler the outer belongs to.

```js
var $spoilers = $('.spoiler').on('click', '.outer', function(e){
  $spoilers.removeClass('active');
  $spoilers.has(e.target).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.spoiler:not(.active) .inner { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler">
    <img class="outer" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner">
    <h1>John Doe</h1>
    <p>President</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum posuere tempus odio, in ornare lacus pulvinar quis. Aliquam sed risus non nisi euismod dignissim quis quis diam.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum posuere tempus odio, in ornare lacus pulvinar quis. Aliquam sed risus non nisi euismod dignissim quis quis diam. Nullam venenatis sit amet massa eget bibendum. Maecenas odio mi, tristique et viverra ac, ornare id enim. Aliquam et felis nibh. Etiam pharetra, nisi a scelerisque consectetur, nibh quam volutpat dui, nec faucibus ante nunc vel nisi. Fusce rutrum tempor auctor. Donec feugiat tellus in feugiat ultrices. Nulla et neque tristique, dictum metus in, dapibus eros. Duis interdum erat eget pellentesque tristique.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler">
    <img class="outer" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner">
    This is a spoiler!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler">
    <img class="outer" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner">
    This is a spoiler!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler">
    <img class="outer" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    <div class="inner">
    This is a spoiler!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, do you happen to know how to make the spoiler span the full widtrh under the boxes like in my image? Thanks so much for your time!